# How to catch Joblib/Parallel Exceptions in python?

Tags: exception, try-catch, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading, joblib

I have a use case for `joblib`'s `Parallel, delayed`. I have included some feature that terminates a worker under certain conditions. However, when I do that, I am randomly yielding `JoblibWebdriverException`, `Multiprocessing exception`, `JoblibURLerror`, or just `error`.

To my great amusement, I don't find any section on how to (define?)/catch Exceptions in the [docs](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/joblib/latest/joblib.pdf).

When I do:

```
    try:
       Parallel(delayed(function))
    except (JoblibWebdriverException | error | 'Multiprocessing exception'): 
    # written with separate excepts in original code
       log_errors()
```

I yield `name JoblibWebdriverException not defined` followed by:

```
---------
Sub-process traceback
---------
Multiprocessing exception:
(trace stack)
```

**How to catch undefined joblib Exceptions when using Parallel in python?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would recommend using `concurrent.Futures` which has robust support for Exception handling. `joblib` is notorious for not being able to raise Exceptions from child processes to the main thread due to way the multi-processing is set up.

Comment: I asked this question a while ago and what you are recommending is the exact thing I ended up doing (ThreadPoolExecutor to be more precise). Upvote & accept for sharing your thoughts.

Comment: Could you provide an alternative solution to this problem? I can't replace joblib as it is deeply entrenched in the sklearn ecosystem.